# Unit testing a Kotlin coroutine with delay

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to unit test a Kotlin coroutine that uses `delay()`. For the unit test I don't care about the `delay()`, it's just slowing the test down. I'd like to run the test in some way that doesn't actually delay when `delay()` is called.

I tried running the coroutine using a custom context which delegates to CommonPool:

```
class TestUiContext : CoroutineDispatcher(), Delay {
    suspend override fun delay(time: Long, unit: TimeUnit) {
        // I'd like it to call this
    }

    override fun scheduleResumeAfterDelay(time: Long, unit: TimeUnit, continuation: CancellableContinuation<Unit>) {
        // but instead it calls this
    }

    override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
        CommonPool.dispatch(context, block)
    }
}
```

I was hoping I could just return from my context's `delay()` method, but instead it's calling my `scheduleResumeAfterDelay()` method, and I don't know how to delegate that to the default scheduler.

Comment: Can't you just make the delay timeout configurable so that in your test you can choose a very small one?!

Comment: @s1m0nw1 Yes, but I'd rather have a general solution, and not have to modify my code like that.

Comment: @eoinmullan, Can you share a minimal git project for the same?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In kotlinx.coroutines v1.6.0 the [kotlinx-coroutines-test](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/) module was updated. It allows tests to use the `runTest()` method and `TestScope` to test suspending code, automatically skipping delays.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/README.md) for details on how to use the module.

### Previous Answer

In kotlinx.coroutines v1.2.1 they added the [kotlinx-coroutines-test](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/) module. It includes the `runBlockingTest` coroutine builder, as well as a `TestCoroutineScope` and `TestCoroutineDispatcher`. They allow auto-advancing time, as well as explicitly controlling time for testing coroutines with `delay`.

Comment: Great resources shared @Erik Browne! Specifically, how would you implement `runBlockingTest`, `TestCoroutineScope`, or `TestCoroutineDispatcher` to handle the `delay` in the unit test?

Comment: I've expanded upon this solution with a specific implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62397243/2253682).

Comment: In kotlinx.coroutines v1.6.0 they revamped the testing library, replacing `TestCoroutineScope` and `TestCoroutineDispatcher` with `TestScope` and `TestDispatcher`.

Comment: @ErikBrowne I recommend that you edit your answer to highlight the recent recommendations with the new version of kotlin coroutines (1.6.0).

Answer (score 30):

If you don't want any delay, why don't you simply resume the continuation in the schedule call?:

```
class TestUiContext : CoroutineDispatcher(), Delay {
    override fun scheduleResumeAfterDelay(time: Long, unit: TimeUnit, continuation: CancellableContinuation<Unit>) {
        continuation.resume(Unit)
    }

    override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
        //CommonPool.dispatch(context, block)  // dispatch on CommonPool
        block.run()  // dispatch on calling thread
    }
}
```

That way `delay()` will resume with no delay.  Note that this still suspends at delay, so other coroutines can still run (like `yield()`)

```
@Test
fun `test with delay`() {
    runBlocking(TestUiContext()) {
        launch { println("launched") }
        println("start")
        delay(5000)
        println("stop")
    }
}
```

Runs without delay and prints:

```
start
launched
stop
```

**EDIT:**

You can control where the continuation is run by customizing the `dispatch` function.

Comment: And `dispatch()` can just be `block.run()`, which keeps execution in the main thread.

Comment: True, and that might make sense for testing, though he seemed to want it to use CommonPool.

Comment: I'm the OP, and I'd rather it use the same thread. Make the change and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: The `Delay` interface is now an internal API in the KotlinX coroutine library. This class, and any class which uses it, must be marked with the `@InternalCoroutinesApi` annotation.

Answer (score 15):

## Use TestCoroutineDispatcher, TestCoroutineScope, or Delay

TestCoroutineDispatcher, TestCoroutineScope, or Delay can be used to handle a `delay` in a Kotlin coroutine made in the production code tested.

### Implement

In this case *SomeViewModel*'s view state is being tested. In the `ERROR` state a view state is emitted with the error value being true. After the defined Snackbar time length has passed using a `delay` a new view state is emitted with the error value set to false.

*SomeViewModel.kt*

```kotlin
private fun loadNetwork() {
    repository.getData(...).onEach {
        when (it.status) {
            LOADING -> ...
            SUCCESS ...
            ERROR -> {
                _viewState.value = FeedViewState.SomeFeedViewState(
                    isLoading = false,
                    feed = it.data,
                    isError = true
                )
                delay(SNACKBAR_LENGTH)
                _viewState.value = FeedViewState.SomeFeedViewState(
                    isLoading = false,
                    feed = it.data,
                    isError = false
                )
            }
        }
    }.launchIn(coroutineScope)
}
```

There are numerous ways to handle the `delay`. `advanceUntilIdle` is good because it doesn't require specifying a hardcoded length. Also, if injecting the TestCoroutineDispatcher, as [outlined by Craig Russell](https://craigrussell.io/2019/11/unit-testing-coroutine-suspend-functions-using-testcoroutinedispatcher/), this will be handled by the same dispatcher used inside of the ViewModel.

*SomeTest.kt*

```kotlin
private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
private val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(testDispatcher)

// Code that initiates the ViewModel emission of the view state(s) here.

testDispatcher.advanceUntilIdle()
```

These will also work:

- `testScope.advanceUntilIdle()`
- `testDispatcher.delay(SNACKBAR_LENGTH)`
- `delay(SNACKBAR_LENGTH)`
- `testDispatcher.resumeDispatcher()`
- `testScope.resumeDispatcher()`
- `testDispatcher.advanceTimeBy(SNACKBAR_LENGTH)`
- `testScope.advanceTimeBy(SNACKBAR_LENGTH)`

### Error without handling the delay

> kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: Unfinished coroutines during teardown. Ensure all coroutines are completed or cancelled by your test.
>
> at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:178)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest.cleanUpTest(FeedTest.kt:127)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest.access$cleanUpTest(FeedTest.kt:28)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest$topCafesTest$1.invokeSuspend(FeedTest.kt:106)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest$topCafesTest$1.invoke(FeedTest.kt)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt$runBlockingTest$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:50)
>       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:288)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:109)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async(Builders.common.kt:91)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async$default(Builders.common.kt:84)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async$default(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:49)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:80)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest.topCafesTest(FeedTest.kt:41)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)

Comment: if I use the `testDispatcher.advanceTimeBy` I get that unfinished coroutines error and I'm not sure how to resolve that. `testDispatcher.advanceUntilIdle` works nicely though

Comment: That is good to hear `advanceUntilIdle` does the job for you. Running the test in a `TestCoroutineDispatcher().runBlockingTest{...}` may resolve the unfinished coroutine error as [outlined by Craig Russell here](https://craigrussell.io/2019/11/unit-testing-coroutine-suspend-functions-using-testcoroutinedispatcher/).

Answer (score 5):

In kotlinx.coroutines v0.23.0 they introduced a [TestCoroutineContext](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.test/-test-coroutine-context/index.html).

Pro: it makes truly testing coroutines with `delay` possible. You can set the CoroutineContext's virtual clock to a moment in time and verify the expected behavior.

Con: if your coroutine code doesn't use `delay`, and you just want it to execute synchronously on the calling thread, it is slightly more cumbersome to use than the `TestUiContext` from @bj0's answer (you need to call `triggerActions()` on the TestCoroutineContext to get the coroutine to execute).

Sidenote:
The `TestCoroutineContext` now lives in the `kotlinx-coroutines-test` module starting with coroutines version 1.2.1, and will be marked deprecated or not exist in the standard coroutine library in versions above this version.

Comment: A quick update that the `TestCoroutineContext` has already been deprecated in later versions of the coroutines library.

Comment: In v1.2.1 they added the experimental [kotlinx-coroutines-test](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test) module, including `runBlockingTest`, `TestCoroutineScope`, and `TestCoroutineDispatcher`.