# Android testing of Kotlin coroutines with TestCoroutineDispatcher (deprecated) alternative

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

im investigating testing of coroutines in my Android application and following this code lab `Advanced Android in Kotlin 05.3: Testing Coroutines and Jetpack integrations`

this codelab contains the following code snippet

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Before
fun setupDispatcher() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@After
fun tearDownDispatcher() {
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
    testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
}
```

however TestCoroutineDispatcher is marked as deprecated with this comment:-

```
/**
 * [CoroutineDispatcher] that performs both immediate and lazy execution of coroutines in tests
 * and uses a [TestCoroutineScheduler] to control its virtual clock.
 *
 * By default, [TestCoroutineDispatcher] is immediate. That means any tasks scheduled to be run without delay are
 * immediately executed. If they were scheduled with a delay, the virtual clock-time must be advanced via one of the
 * methods on the dispatcher's [scheduler].
 *
 * When switched to lazy execution using [pauseDispatcher] any coroutines started via [launch] or [async] will
 * not execute until a call to [DelayController.runCurrent] or the virtual clock-time has been advanced via one of the
 * methods on [DelayController].
 *
 * @see DelayController
 */
@Deprecated("The execution order of `TestCoroutineDispatcher` can be confusing, and the mechanism of " +
    "pausing is typically misunderstood. Please use `StandardTestDispatcher` or `UnconfinedTestDispatcher` instead.",
    level = DeprecationLevel.WARNING)
// Since 1.6.0, ERROR in 1.7.0 and removed as experimental in 1.8.0
public class TestCoroutineDispatcher(public override val scheduler: TestCoroutineScheduler = TestCoroutineScheduler()):
    TestDispatcher(), Delay, SchedulerAsDelayController
{...}
```

It is not clear how I should use the suggested alternatives to `TestCoroutineDispatcher()` are `StandardTestDispatcher` and `UnconfinedTestDispatcher` straight replacements for TestCoroutineDispatcher()?

what am I missing?

Comment: I use `UnconfinedTestDispatcher` as `testDispatcher` and `runTest()` in unit-test. See also https://craigrussell.io/2022/01/19/comparing-standardtestdispatcher-and-unconfinedtestdispatcher, https://medium.com/@ralf.stuckert/testing-coroutines-update-1-6-0-701d53546683.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems it is possible to use more elegant solution like `runTest()` since `1.6.0`

Taken from this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171302/unit-testing-a-kotlin-coroutine-with-delay)

See the [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/README.md) for details on how to use the module.

Comment: Thanks, I was spending hours trying to match a deprecated function when using the most recent one was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Ide suggests `StandardTestDispatcher()`, however, its not behaving like `TestCoroutineDispatcher()` as `StandardTestDispatcher()` won't enter `launch{}` or `async{}` immediately. Therefore, its better to use `UnconfinedTestDispatcher()`. I suggest you to check the quick documentation in android studio to get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

#### Testing coroutines Resources

- [Official Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test)
- [commonsware's free pdf book on coroutines](https://commonsware.com/Coroutines/)
- [Official Kotlin documentation on testing coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/README.md)
- `Kotlin coroutines by tutorial by Filip Babic, Luka Kordić, and Nishant Srivastava` (paid resource but worth the money)

#### What I am currently testing

- So currently I am using the code below to unit test a viewModel

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class HomeViewModelTest {
    
     var twitchRepoImpl: TwitchRepo = mock(TwitchRepo::class.java)
    
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun testingGetLiveChannels()= runTest {
        /**GIVEN*/

        val unconfinedDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)
        val standardDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher(testScheduler)
        Dispatchers.setMain(unconfinedDispatcher)

        val response = Response.Success(listOf(StreamInfo("","","",0,"","")))

        `when`(twitchRepoImpl.getFollowedLiveStreams("","","")).thenReturn(flow { emit(response) })

        try{
            val homeViewModel = HomeViewModel(
                twitchRepoImpl=twitchRepoImpl,
                ioDispatcher=unconfinedDispatcher
            )

            /**WHEN*/
            homeViewModel.getLiveStreams("","","")

            val actualValue = homeViewModel.state.value.streamersListLoading
            val expectedResponse = Response.Success(true)
            
            /**THEN*/

            Assert.assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualValue)
        }finally {
            Dispatchers.resetMain()
        }
        
    }
}
```

- The tests pass and fail when I want them to. So the unit tests do work. However, there is still a question of using `UnconfinedTestDispatcher` or `StandardTestDispatcher` ?

#### StandardTestDispatcher vs UnconfinedTestDispatcher

- my tests from the code above passes no matter which dispatcher I use. However, if we look at the documentation for [StandardTestDispatcher](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-standard-test-dispatcher.html)  and [UnconfinedTestDispatcher](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-unconfined-test-dispatcher.html) we can see that there are differences.

#### What are the differences and which should I use?

- the main differences seem to be about control. Where the [StandardTestDispatcher](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-standard-test-dispatcher.html)  does not immediately run the coroutine, it instead sends it to the `scheduler` which we can then access and have further control over our tests.
- Which one should you use? If there are no advanced cases you need to test then just use [UnconfinedTestDispatcher](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-unconfined-test-dispatcher.html). My code is currently working fine and I am using the UnconfinedTestDispatcher. However, if there comes a time where you need a bit more control over when and how your coroutine runs, then use [StandardTestDispatcher](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-standard-test-dispatcher.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe we have a small misunderstanding here regarding the substitution of `Dispatcher.Main` for a suitable one for testing purposes and the usage of runTest.

What we are trying to achieve here by using Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher) is to replace the use of the Main dispatcher in our tests with a test dispatcher that we will provide. It is important to note that the Main dispatcher is specific to the Android platform, so you don't have access to it in platform-independent unit tests, right?

Let's first explain when to use UnconfinedTestDispatcher and when to use StandardTestDispatcher.

**UnconfinedTestDispatcher** is suitable for tests where you want to execute coroutine code immediately It doesn't introduce any delay or asynchronous behavior during test execution

**StandardTestDispatcher** allows you to control and manipulate time, so you can advance the virtual time in your tests to trigger timeouts, delays, and other time-related behavior

For simple cases, you can use UnconfinedTestDispatcher like this:

```kotlin
class MainDispatcherRule(private val dispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) :
    TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

In your class with tests, add:

```kotlin
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()
```

If you try to write a test for a function in which Dispatcher.Main is used and you do not swap Main for TestDispatcher, you will receive an exception like:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used`

You can easily encounter this while writing tests for your ViewModel class in which you use viewModelScope.

Using `runTest` will not solve that. `runTest` is like `runBlocking` with the additional feature of skipping delays. `runBlocking`, on the other hand, is used to run asynchronous code in a synchronous way.

Even when using `runTest`, we still need to replace the Main dispatcher with a TestDispatcher in situations where Main is already used.